# preg_match как выделить слово, за которым нет другого слова?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пример текста:

> В городе Грайворон Белгородской области установили мировой рекорд – собрали самый многочисленный узорный хоровод. Более 2,5 тысячи человек 84 минуты танцевали, взявшись за руки. В городе Белгороде прошли испытания. Они "завернули" хоровод в семь совершенно разных замысловатых фигур, причем финальный узор вместе с артистами строили и зрители

Мне нужно выделить отдельно:

- Название области
- Название города

область выделяю следующей регуляркой:

```
preg_match('/белгород.{1,5} област/ui',$text,$matches);
```

А вот как с помощью регулярок выделить только город без области? Другими словами выделить "белгород.{1,5}" после которого не идет "област"???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Утверждения касательно последующего текста начинаются с `(?=` для положительных утверждений и с `(?!` для отрицающих утверждений.
Утверждения касательно предшествующего текста начинаются с `(?<=` для положительных утверждений и `(?<!` для отрицающих.

Например, `'/(?<!foo)bar/`' не найдёт вхождения *"bar"*, которым не
предшествует *"foo"*. Т.е. `qwefoobar` этот шаблон проигнорирует, а
`asacdbar` под него подойдет. `(?<=\d{3})(?<!999)foo` совпадает с
подстрокой *"foo"*, которой предшествуют три цифры, отличные от *"999"*.
Следует понимать, что каждое из утверждений проверяется относительно
одной и той же позиции в обрабатываемом тексте. Утверждения могут быть
вложенными, причем в произвольных сочетаниях: `(?<=(?<!foo)bar)baz`
соответствует подстроке *"baz"*, которой предшествует "bar", перед
которой, в свою очередь, нет *'foo'*.

Comment: Только сам нашел ответ на вопрос, и тут ты его дал, но все равно спасибо!

Comment: Вообще надо сначала искать ,а потом, когда либо ничего не найдено, либо найденное - не понято, вот тогда  задавать вопрос..

Comment: искал долго до этого